# Creating a subset from a dataframe

Tags: python, subset

I have been trying to create a subset test_df from my raw_df based on the show_name.
However, it does not seem to work. I am getting the entire raw_df as a part of my subset.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
train_df = raw_df[raw_df['data_source']!='20DU']
test_df = raw_df[raw_df['data_source'] == '20DU']
test_df = raw_df.drop(columns='id')


Output:
Train_df shape: (279567, 19)
Test_df shape:  (309207, 18)
Raw_df shape (309207, 19)
```

Not sure what is going wrong here. Does anybody have an idea how to overcome the issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd probably want `test_df = test_df.drop(columns='id')` currently you are reassigning your raw_df to your test_df in the 3rd line

Comment: `test_df = test_df.drop(columns='id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented by ScootCork and Andreas, you are basically overwriting your first `test_df` assignment.
Either

```
test_df = raw_df[raw_df['data_source'] == '20DU']
test_df = test_df.drop(columns='id')
```

or the slightly compressed version

```
test_df = raw_df[raw_df['data_source'] == '20DU'].drop(columns='id')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. The compressed version helps avoid such human errors.
Will use this style more often now :)

Comment: @Reshma2k You are welcome. Feel free to upvote if you find the post helpful ;)